# Not getting a result after async firebase "set( )" function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I do not get any result after I run the "set( )" function to the "res" variable when running this code, meaning that the "res" variable is undefined even though the docuement gets created in firebase. I have tried .then() .catch() too and that doesn't give me any kind of result either. The document gets created and everything works, and I if I want I can just return the Promise no matter the outcome of the firebase function, but that feels like it's bad practice since Im overlooking a possible error right?

Can I somehow get a result from "set( )" function? or in some other way make sure that the "set( )" function is successful?

```
exports.create = async function(listId, name, link) {
    const newLinkRef = db.firestore.collection('links').doc();

    const data = {
        id: newLinkRef.id,
        listId: listId,
        name: name,
        link: link
    };

    var res = await newLinkRef.set(data);
    console.log(res)

    if (res.id) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {resolve({error: null, linkId: res.Id})})
    } else {
        return new Promise(resolve => {resolve({error: "Error creating lint"})})
    }
}
```

(I use the "set( )" function over the "add( )" funciton since I want to save the random created Id inside the object stored to, and this was the simplest way I could find to do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set()` returns a promise, but your use of `await` consume that promise and leaves `res` as the result that the promise wraps, which is `void`. So `undefined` seems correct there.

I think you're looking for:

```
try {
  var res = await newLinkRef.set(data);
  return {error: null, linkId: newLinkRef.Id};
}
catch (e) {
  return {error: "Error creating lint"}
}
```

---

Alternatively you can not use `await`, and you end up with:

```
return newLinkRef.set(data).then(() => {
  return {error: null, linkId: newLinkRef.Id};
}).catch (e) => {
  return {error: "Error creating lint"}
})
```